# Azure SQL server - SQLLoginAdministrator PW Reset cmdlet/command

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, passwords

Anybody knows an Azure cmdlet/cli command to reset the SQLLoginAdminstrator's password?

All I've been seeing is a GUI based in the Azure portal for this but I was hoping to find any command related to this since we might need to reset hundreds of Azure SQL servers for policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use [Set-AzureRmSqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.sql/v1.0.12/set-azurermsqlserver)

```
PS C:\>$ServerPassword = "newpassword"
PS C:\> $SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $ServerPassword -AsPlainText -Force
PS C:\> Set-AzureRmSqlServer -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01" -SqlAdministratorPassword $secureString
```

Also, you could refer to this [link](http://www.mikefal.net/2016/05/04/azure-sql-databases-with-powershell-managing-your-databases/).